# How to make tmux count windows starting from 1 instead of 0?

Tags: tmux

I was able to make GNU Screen start counting windows with the number 1 instead of the default 0 with this code in my .screenrc:

```
# Get rid of screen 0
bind c screen 1
bind ^c screen 1
bind 0 select 10
```

When I created windows in .screenrc I used `screen 1` so that it would first try 1 and then count up if that window number was taken.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

The solution is to modify `~/.tmux.conf` to:

```
# Start windows and panes at 1, not 0
set -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1
```

Edit: unlike base-index, pane-base-index is a window option, so setw should be used, as @Jogusa pointed out.

Comment: I wish they made this default, its really inconvenient as 0 as at the other side of the keyboard.

Comment: According to my tmux book it shoud be `setw` in the pane setting: `setw -g pane-base-index 1` See the .tmux.conf from book: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/bhtmux/code/config/tmux.conf

Comment: What's the significance of setw vs set?

Comment: `setw` is alias for `set-window-option` or `set -w`. Altering `pane-base-index` is a window option. See tmux manpage ->  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/tmux.1.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to change window numbering in interactive window chooser (C-b w). [Bug report](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/670)

Comment: i still have no idea, up till this day, why numbers on the keyboard start from 1 instead of 0. what kind of ordering is that?

Comment: I'm annoyed it took me so many months to think to search for this answer

Comment: Note that `tmux` has to restart for windows to start at `1`. In contrast, panes will start at `1` just by doing `<prefix> :source-file ~/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: @Gerald: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76446/why-is-the-0-next-to-9-not-next-to-1

Comment: I turned this into a TPM plugin if anyone finds that to be more convenient. It's a pretty straightforward config, admittedly, but if I can figure out a way to also renumber sessions I'll add that to the plugin as well: https://github.com/openjck/tmux-one

Comment: I had to do `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` before this worked.